# Flutter: Why is a sequence of plus characters in a Text widget not treated as a single word?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following image you can tell that there is a line break introduced within +++++ when it exceeds the container width, whereas in ***** there is no line break:

[image: line nbreak]

The example can be reproduced with the following Flutter code:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.yellow,
  width: 60,
  child: const Text('+++++ +++++ +++++'),
),
const SizedBox(height: 20),
Container(
  color: Colors.yellow,
  width: 60,
  child: const Text('***** ***** *****'),
),
```

How can I tell Flutter not to line break the pluses?

**EDIT**: I checked with different editors and Libre Office Writer. They all break ++. So, there's nothing wrong with Flutter's behavior.

Comment: I don't know why asterisks don't break but you check  [TextOverflow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextOverflow.html) to set/change the overflow methods.

Comment: TextOverflow doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```dart
"++++ ++++ ++++".replaceAll("\u{200B}", "")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.